# CSS buttons not displaying in IE 8/10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, button

Currently I have creating some pure CSS buttons for a few customer pages. They display fine in all browsers except IE 8/10. They do however display the styles (mostly) if the css is applied as an inline style OR if I turn on compatibility mode (which is off by default).

Here is the page: http://www.americasfinestpolice.com/patrolmens-benevolent-association-custom-watches.aspx

```
#btn-a-1, #btn-a-3, #btn-a-5, #btn-a-7, #btn-a-9, #btn-a-11 {
    outline: none !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3) !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: .5em !important; 
    -moz-border-radius: .5em !important;
    border-radius: .5em !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2 !important);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2) !important;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2) !important;
    color: #FFF !important;
    border: solid 1px #F61208 !important;
    background: #F61205 !important;
    background-color: #F61205 !important;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#F61205), to(#9F0601)) !important;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #F61205,  #9F0601) !important;
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F61205 0%, #9F0601 100%) !important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #F61205 0%, #9F0601 100%) !important;
    height: 1% !important;
    width: 230px !important;
    color: #FFF !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    display: block !important;
}
<div class="btn btn-1"><a href="/nycpbawatches.aspx">
<div class="btn-text btn-2">

NYC PBA Mens<br />Chronograph Watch<br />(CLICK HERE)

</div>
</a>
</div>
```

Please and thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I can see lots of reasons why they won't work in IE8.

Comment: You shouldn't have block level elements like `div`s inside anchors. I would try and swap `btn-2` to a `<span>` instead.

Comment: Oh, and try to avoid using `!important`. It's a sign that your CSS code is badly written.

Comment: I must say that is one heck of a large background, load me up....

Comment: also its `!important` that you should not use `!important`

Comment: Actually, the css you posted does nothing for elements with class `btn`, `btn-1`, `btn-text` or `btn-2`.

Comment: Actually, I see it only working in WebKit browsers. It doesn't work in IE, Opera, or Firefox. They're not receiving the styles set on the anchor element. I suspect there is something wrong with the selector, which is making non-webkit browsers drop it, but I've not spotted it yet.